# Mui: como cambiar el title color in a ImageListItemBar

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Estoy intentand cambiar el color del titulo pero el editor me arrojo un error si lo hago de la siguiente forma. Intente hacerlo tambien poniendo directamente "color: "black"" pero no lo reconoce.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<ImageListItem>
                  <Image src={image} alt={pet?.name}/>
                  <ImageListItemBar
                    title={pet?.name}
                    sx={{
                      margin: "1rem",
                      borderRadius: ".5rem",
                      background: "white",
                      opacity: "0.8",
                      "&.MuiImageListItemBar-title": {
                        color: "black",
                      }
                    }}/>
                </ImageListItem>:
```

Answer (score 0):

Deberia de ser solo un error de syntaxis...lo correcto seria:

```
<ImageListItemBar title={pet?.name}
sx={{margin:"1rem",
borderRadius:".5rem",
background:"white",
opacity:"0.8",
"&.MuiImageListItemBar-title":{color:"black",
}
}} />
```